# Unable to open file in C

Tags: c

i am working in C and want to open a simple text file then perform some processing over it. My code looks like

```
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("d:\\series.txt", "r");

if (pFile == NULL)
{
    printf("File not found or Unable to open file\nPress any key to continue . . ." );
        getch();
        return;
    }   
    else
    {
         //process here
    }
```

every time the condition becomes true
    if (pFile == NULL)
so i am not able to perform processing on file.

I check that file exist in my drive with same name and its open properly when i double click on it

Comment: probably you don't have permissions to read it. Put it in d:\some_dir\ and try again.

Comment: capital D for a drive letter? Seems like you're on Windows?

Comment: @Henno: Windows does not require capital letters for drives. In fact, Windows filesystems are overwhelmingly case-insensitive in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting this inside the `if` block:

```
perror(NULL);
```

That should give a descriptive error message, so you know what went wrong.